# Defining startup cron job with screen running django

Tags: django, cron, gnu-screen

I want to run my development django server at startup so I defined following cron job:

```
@reboot screen -d -m django-admin.py runserver 192.168.0.28:8000
```

But it didn't work.

What is really interesting, when I copy/paste directly to terminal and execute it works just fine.

I even tried something like this:

```
@reboot cd /home/ubuntu && /usr/bin/screen -d -m /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py runserver 192.168.0.28:8000 &> /home/ubuntu/cron.err
```

To be sure I'm not using some undefined commands in wrong location and examined contents of cron.err file but it's empty.

And (of course) when I fire this directly from the console it works immediately.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you try and run it from cron at a specific time? Eg:

```
50 12 2 8 * /usr/bin/screen -dmS set_from_cron
```

Comment: Perfect, you gave me very nice hint! According to this article : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1530652 I shouldn't call any script that resides in the /home directory, because it can be not mounted yet. It should be moved to /usr instead.